# Iterators in VB.NET vNext, and limitations of iterators in C#

Tags: vb.net, iterator, c#-5.0

I just saw on the [Async CTP website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx) that the next version of VB.NET will have iterators. I guess they included iterators because the rewriting process is similar to the one used for the new `async`/`await` feature.

But reading the document that explains the feature, I realized that VB.NET iterators will actually have features that are not available in C# today, namely:

- iterator blocks in a try/catch block
- anonymous iterator blocks

These were known limitations in C#. Is there any chance that these limitations will be removed in C# 5 ? If not, is there any reason why it can be done in VB.NET and not in C# ?

Comment: Vb.net has always been about language innovation, c#, although a nice language, hasn't had language innovation at it's core. Basically, vb.net is a better language if u don't buy into the bad rep it had pre .net days.c# no XML literals, no intellisense on xdocument, less built in keywords over linq to anything, no with clause, less readable, should I continue?

Comment: C# is less functional and people like this because they feel smarter and cooler using a language that has less language innovation. They buy into the C/C++ marketing angle and use c# because they think it's cooler and forget that vb6 != vb.net

Comment: The question is not about VB.NET being better or worse than C#, so please don't start trolling... C# certainly doesn't have less innovations than VB. It had iterators since version 2 (3 versions earlier than VB). Lambda expressions in VB where much more limited than in C# in VS2008. I personnally consider XML literals to be a Bad Thing™, and VB is much too verbose for my taste. As for readability, I find C# much more readable. The two languages are mostly equivalent (functionnally) nowadays, so you see, it's mostly a matter of personal preference... So please avoid this kind of useless comment

Comment: BTW, too bad we can't downvote comments...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any chance that these limitations will be removed in C# 5 ?

There is a slim chance. I certainly wouldn't count on it. Those are "nice to have" features, not "must have" features, and when you have an *enormous* amount of work to do, the "nice to have" features sometimes fall off the schedule, as nice as they are.

> If not, is there any reason why it can be done in VB.NET and not in C# ?

Any technical reason? No. There are engineering reasons of course.

Often it is the case that being the second team to implement a particular feature is beneficial. The implementors of a second implementation get to take advantage of the knowledge gained from the first attempt without taking on so large a research and development cost, while not incurring any maintenance or backwards compatibility taxes.

VB has the benefit of not having had this feature already and therefore has no existing body of millions of lines of user code that they need to be 100% backwards compatible with. That is a considerable cost burden removed. And they have a large database of bug reports, design notes, and so on, from eight years of having this feature in C#.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that makes sense of course... I just don't like to admit that VB has something more than C# ;)

Comment: Or as Gilad Bracha put it in the PDC talk: "Once you have users, it's all over" :-)

Comment: @Thomas: VB has XML literals also.

Comment: @Eric, yes, but it doesn't really count, because it's a feature I definitely don't want in C# ;)

Comment: Thomas, you don't want XML literals in C#? You must not work in 'an enterprise setting'. ;) For my current project, we have a dedicated VB.NET project only to handle the XML files. Even though I prefer C# for everything, XML literals in VB.NET simply rock. Not only you can develop faster, XML literals code is at least 5 times more readable (and hence maintainable) than comparable code in C#. For me, XML literals are much more useful than anonymous iterator blocks and iterator blocks in try/catch. Your mileage may vary. Eric, how's the demand for XML literals in C#?

Comment: @SolutionYogi, I don't know, I really don't like the idea... XML is data, and data embedded in code just feels *wrong*. However, I agree that the VB.NET syntax for Linq to XML is very handy...

Comment: What happened to that old age saying 'Code is data' and 'Data is code.'? ;) Jokes aside, have you ever had need to produce different kind of XML outputs. Look at the code sample on this page: http://bradraulston.blogspot.com/2007/09/xml-literals-in-vb-90.html The tags 'SnappingOptions', 'Boundry', 'EndPoint' are actually part of code and VB.NET makes it very easy to see the structure without all the XElement noise. Write the same code in C# and you would see how much boiler plate code C# adds to output such a simple XML fragment.

Comment: And that's not all, you even get Intellisense support if you have the right XML schema. This screenshot shows Intellisense in action for Office XML. http://imgur.com/38PJ3 I can't tell you how much time I have saved thanks to Intellisense. Again, XElement in C# doesn't have any Intellisense support. I would really urge you to actually use XML Literals for actual code before discounting them. Once you try it, you would never want to do XML manipulation in any other language, I can bet on that.

Comment: is this going is as part of the roslyn rewrite?