# Collection Initializers with Automatic Properties

Tags: .net, collections, syntax, properties

Is there a way to use a collection initializer when also using automatic properties?

```
// Uses collection initializer but not automatic properties
private List<int> _numbers = new List<int>();
public List<int> Numbers
{
    get { return _numbers; }
    set { _numbers = value; }
}


// Uses automatic properties but not collection initializer
public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }


// Is there some way to do something like this??
public List<int> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<int>();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [automatic property with default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691888/automatic-property-with-default-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, basically. You would have to initialize the collection in the constructor. To be honest, a settable collection is rarely a good idea *anyway*; I would actually use just (changing your first version, removing the `set`):

```
private readonly List<int> _numbers = new List<int>();
public List<int> Numbers { get { return _numbers; } }
```

or if I want to defer construction until the first access:

```
private List<int> _numbers;
public List<int> Numbers {
    get { return _numbers ?? (_numbers = new List<int>()); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `// Is there some way to do something like this??`
>
> `public List<int> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<int>();`

No. You have to initialize in an explicitly-defined constructor, there are no field-initialization tricks to apply here.

Also, this has nothing to do with collection intializers. You also can't initialize

```
public object Foo { get; set; }
```

outside of a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

apparently your voice was heard.
I just stumbled across this being used for the first time in a new codebase.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

> "In C# 6 and later, you can initialize auto-implemented properties
> similarly to fields:"

```
public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Jane";
```